# C++ Simple Thread Start Issue

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have fairly simple code, and every example I find looks fairly similar.  I'm sure I'm missing something basic, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*-------------------------------------
State
--------------------------------------*/
void Receiver::start(int num_threads = 1) {
    _kill_mtx.lock();
    _kill_state = false;
    _kill_mtx.unlock();
    for (int i=0; i<num_threads; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(thread_func));  // LINE 24

    std::cout << threads.size() << " now running.\n";
    std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << " concurrent threads are supported.\n";
}

void Receiver::stop() {

}

/*-------------------------------------
Thread
--------------------------------------*/
void Receiver::thread_func() {
    while(true) {
        if (_kill_mtx.try_lock()) {
            if (_kill_state) {
                break;
            }
            _kill_mtx.unlock();
        }
        std::cout << "Still Alive!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It is compiled using `-std=c++0x -lstdc++ -ldbus-c++-1 -pthread` and outputs the errors:

```
 communication.cpp: In member function 'void Receiver::start(int)':
| communication.cpp:24:47: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved
 overloaded function type>, int&)'
| communication.cpp:24:47: note: candidates are:
| /home/toor/bluegiga-sdk/build/tmp/sysroots/apx4devkit/usr/include/c++/thread:133:7: note: std::th
read::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Receiver::*)(int), _Args = {int&}]
| /home/toor/bluegiga-sdk/build/tmp/sysroots/apx4devkit/usr/include/c++/thread:133:7: note:   no kn
own conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (Receiver::*&&)
(int)'
```

The GCC compiler is an ARM compiler provided by the SDK I'm building with.  It so far has supported most of the other C++11 features I've tried, so I don't think it's the issue, but I'm not certain.

Comment: What is `threads`,and is `thread_func` a non-static member function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that `Receiver::thread_func` is a non-static member function, in which case you need to pass the implicit first parameter. Assuming you want the thread to operate in the same instance, you need to pass `this`. Otherwise you need to pass a pointer to another `Receiver` instance:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(&Receiver::thread_func, this));
```

Comment: That worked.  I figured that out a minute after posting this question, but I didn't understand why.  That makes sense now.  Thank you!